# UI test Automation of .Net application on Jenkins, How?

Tags: .net, jenkins, automated-tests, sikuli

If it is a web base. I know that we can use selenium.

But This case is .Net Windows-based application. So, is this possible? and how to do it?

I checked NUnit but it is more like unit testes than UI test.
I checked Autoit but I still don't understand how to use it on Jenkins.
I checked Robot Framework with AutoIt lib but I cannot find much example about it.

I found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188784.aspx but it is like create an app to test the target app.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jenkins.  You need to look for "automated testing tools for .Net app".  Once that is working on your dev machine, you can move to jenkins.  (Running Jenkins slave that can interact with desktop is usually enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a FREE solution for this.

I can use www.sikuli.org with Jenkins to test Windows applications.
Sikuli uses the concept of image recognition. The good things about this are that:

- FREE , I can develop/maintain the app with .Net community version
- I can write test with my prefer language which is Java (or python)
- None-tech guys can easily create automate tests themselves because Sikuli provides IDE (it is not perfect but it just works)

However, there are some limitations:

- Sikuli itself, sometime, works incorrectly if you have created target images from one resolution but running tests on different resolutions.
- Since Sikuli relates to UI things, it cannot run in background on Jenkins or in background on Windows. I have to make it run via Jenkins slave via Java Webstart and I must open a screen (or the remote desktop) before start the tests.